# How to fire query on database and filter data in SSRS ?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to create SSRS report but I don't want to pull all data from database. I tried to follow "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345246.aspx#Textbased" but it's not clear enough.

Comment: Are you wanting to use parameters for your report? Do you have the ability to create parameters for your data source, on the data source?

Comment: Actually I want to know where to write queries, perhaps a good tutorial which can teach things step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE Field = @ParameterName
```

Comment: Yup, something of this sort, but where to write this query? I am unable to find editor for this

Comment: Under Report data tab. There's a folder for Dataset. Right click that then click Add new Dataset. You have an option there to write a query or use a SP.